# Extending (not implementing) Java interfaces in Clojure

Tags: clojure, jna

I've been looking a lot at Clojure recently and I've been wondering if it suits the scope of my next project.  Unfortunately, it involves writing non-portable code and I need access to the Win32 API.

I stumbled upon  the [Java Native Access](http://jna.java.net/) library for easily mapping native libraries with a C interface into Java.  It even provides an (empty) wrapper for `Kernel32.dll` as an example in the tutorial!

However, I'm a bit stumped as to translating the examples from Java to Clojure.  I know I can [implement interfaces and implement classes](http://clojure.org/java_interop), but how can I simply *extend an interface*?

---

Thanks to the link posted by Joost, here is a minimal working example:

```
(import (com.sun.jna Library Native Platform Pointer))
(import (com.sun.jna.win32 StdCallLibrary))

(def K32
     (gen-interface
      :name Kernel32
      :extends [com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary]
      :methods [[GetCurrentProcess [] com.sun.jna.Pointer]]))

(defn load-native-library [name interface]
  (cast interface (com.sun.jna.Native/loadLibrary name interface)))

(def k32 (load-native-library "kernel32" K32))

(println (.GetCurrentProcess k32))
```

Outputs `#<Pointer native@0xffffffff>`, as expected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only extend an interface with another interface. I'm at a loss why you'd need that functionality when accessing an existing API - even in Java. Just implement it and be done with it.

EDIT: and usually, in my experience, it's much clearer to write your interfaces in pure Java; the usual reason for defining a new Interface in clojure is when you want to add a Java-friendly interface to some clojure code anyway.

EDIT AGAIN: You can use definterface if you find that more attractive for this case. [This blog post](http://nakkaya.com/2009/11/16/java-native-access-from-clojure/) has a few examples using it for accessing JNA.

Comment: Because the JNA code seems to generate the backing class for me.  Check out the "How To Get Started Using JNA" sestion in the posted link.

Comment: Note that  `clojure.core` does provide mechanisms to define Java interfaces in Clojure.  See http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/definterface.  However, it doesn't seem to support extending an *existing* interface.  This seems like a huge limitation.

Comment: @Andre: OK, my java is rusty enough that I can't really see if you really do need to define a new interface there or if you can get away with anything else. I'm updating my answer again.

Comment: Seems to me clear enough from their examples.  You define a new interface that extends `com.sun.jna.Library`, pass that type as the second argument to `com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary()` and cast the returned object to your new interface.  I bet the call to `loadLibrary` uses reflection to generate the implementation class that actually calls the mapped methods.

Comment: Re: your earlier comment: def-interface does allow extending an existing interface, AFAICS. using the (:extends [interface ...]) option

Comment: Thanks, the blog post is *precisely* what I needed!

Comment: Note one limitation of `definterface` is that it does *not* support varargs on the Java signatures